# DAX Match Row then Multiply each Column by matched value keeping Column structure

Tags: filter, dax, lookup, powerbi-desktop, cartesian-product

I am not sure if I am missing something obvious, as I am new to the DAX language.

I have 2 tables, one contains equipment with total quantities, the other has the corresponding set of components for each piece of equipment.

I need to calculate a new table that first matches the equipment in each row, then multiplies each column in the SKU table by the total equipment, while keeping the SKU column structure.

This table needs to be easily expanded as new equipment will be added, which results in more SKU.

I have included small examples, however the actual tables are significantly larger. Tables can be transposed to better suit what ever calculations need specific layouts

Equipment Summary Table:

| Equipment | QTY |
| --- | --- |
| AA | 7 |
| BB | 4 |
| CC | 20 |

SKU table:

| Equipment | SKU#1 | SKU#2 | SKU#3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AA | 2 | 2 | 8 |
| BB | 1 | 0 | 4 |
| CC | 0 | 1 | 0 |

Desired Table:

| Equipment | SKU#1 | SKU#2 | SKU#3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AA | 14 | 14 | 56 |
| BB | 4 | 0 | 16 |
| CC | 0 | 20 | 0 |

I can transfer/match the data via the Lookupvalue function, however the multiplication is still an issue

```
Match Model count = LOOKUPVALUE('Equipment Summary Table'[Qty],'Equipment Summary Table'[Equipment], 'SKU table'[Equipment])
```

I have tired the Product & ProductX functions, however they summarise the data in the columns.

It seems to be a cartesian product, but split per row.
It is similar to this post, however the issue is that I can't get it to automatically expand for all columns in the SKU table.

https://community.fabric.microsoft.com/t5/DAX-Commands-and-Tips/DAX-Fetch-base-value-of-1-column-and-multiply-it-to-all-the-rows/m-p/2749844

Comment: I think you're confusing data table design and presentation. if you unpivot the SKU table so it looks like this: (EquipmentID, SKU#, Qty), then you can just do math once you've joined the two tables. (SUM/SUMPRODUCT etc). Check out UNPIVOT operator in PowerQuery.

Comment: Thanks Pieter, I'll give it a try!
It looks like that will be the fix for it